# Free rules in Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

The pricing document says 5 rules are included for free.
Does this limit apply at subscription level / DCN profile level or endpoint level?

[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/#:~:text=Five%20rules%20are%20included%20for%20free%20(including%20the%20global%20rule)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/#:%7E:text=Five%20rules%20are%20included%20for%20free%20(including%20the%20global%20rule))

Answer (score 1):

Azure Standard CDN from Microsoft (classic) (S3) includes five rules for free (including the global rule).

This is not a limitation at subscription level but rather pricing policy that relates to CDN endpoint.

Each Azure CDN endpoint can have up to 25 rules.
Each rule can have up to ten match conditions and five actions. Pricing for Rules Engine follows the below dimensions:

- Rules: $1 per rule per month
- Requests Processed: $0.60 per million requests
- The first 5 rules will remain free

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/56114/how-can-i-add-additional-rules-to-my-cdn.html

Subscription and service limits for Azure CDN could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#content-delivery-network-limits)